# Resample time-series and show time of day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

This is driving me crazy. I am trying to find the maximum daily value for a time series while showing the time of day when it occurred. I have a datetimeindex, a second datetime column, and a max temperature. If I do

```
temperature_max = temperature.resample('D').max()
```

I get maximum values for both time (23:59) and temperature. How can I get the time of day when max temperature occurred? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need `idxmax` for index of max `temperature` and then select by `loc`:

```
temperature_max = temperature.loc[temperature.resample('D')['temperature'].idxmax()]
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
r = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='12H')
temperature = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'temperature': range(10)}, index=r)  
print (temperature)
                          Date  temperature
2017-04-03 00:00:00 2017-04-03            0
2017-04-03 12:00:00 2017-04-04            1
2017-04-04 00:00:00 2017-04-05            2
2017-04-04 12:00:00 2017-04-06            3
2017-04-05 00:00:00 2017-04-07            4
2017-04-05 12:00:00 2017-04-08            5
2017-04-06 00:00:00 2017-04-09            6
2017-04-06 12:00:00 2017-04-10            7
2017-04-07 00:00:00 2017-04-11            8
2017-04-07 12:00:00 2017-04-12            9

temperature_max = temperature.loc[temperature.resample('D')['temperature'].idxmax()]
print (temperature_max)
                          Date  temperature
2017-04-03 12:00:00 2017-04-04            1
2017-04-04 12:00:00 2017-04-06            3
2017-04-05 12:00:00 2017-04-08            5
2017-04-06 12:00:00 2017-04-10            7
2017-04-07 12:00:00 2017-04-12            9
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking. Thanks!